# Boolean operator for $0$ and$ 1$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> How I can prove this relation for $A$ and $B$ which all entries are  $0$ and $1$ 
>   $(B\lor A) + (B\land A) =B+A$

Can any one help me to prove it ?
$(B\lor A)$ that mean in sets the uion, in matrices is 1 1=0,1 0=1, 
0 1=1
,0 0=1.
Now the $B\land A$ is the intersection

Comment: How did you define the + operator for boolean matrices? Point wise OR? Maybe you could provide context about $A$ and $B$, because either this is almost trivial, or I am completely missing the point.

Comment: @Pieter21 component wise "xor", I'd say. That at least makes it true. And $\oplus$ = xor is addition modulo $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 cases for each entry ($A_{ij},B_{ij}$ have two possible values each). I'd say, check all the cases. And if it holds per entry, it holds for the whole matrix.

Comment: this is prove  enough

Comment: Sure it is. Why wouldn't it be?@MaryamFasfous

Comment: this relation in my master thesis and will to prove it , i think to prove it as you

Comment: I think OP said that $A$ and $B$ are matrices with all entries 0 and 1, not single boolean values.  If that is the case then your answer doesn't make sense, and the question needs clarification: what are $\wedge$ and $\vee$ here?

Comment: v OR operation  and the other is AND operation

Comment: @MJD the OP doesn't mention matrices, but the $\lor$ and $\land$ are usually defined entry-wise if they are, and then it suffices to check it for all single entries, hence $4$ cases.

Comment: @MaryamFasfous It's defined entry-wise I suppose?

Comment: ok you understand what i mean by 0-1 i mean all entries are 0 or 1 so we have 4 case

Comment: The title of the question is “Boolean operator for 0−1
matrices”

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what about this relation can you help me to prove it (B)NOR(A) < (B)OR(A)

Comment: @MaryamFasfous We can only help you, if you edit your post to tell us what $A \land B$ and $A \lor B$ mean for two $0$-$1$ -matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You could also check that both sides, when intersected with A , notA, B, notB produce the same result.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma i edit it